# how to get to the properties of an object inside of it javascript

Tags: javascript, object

I would like to get 'experiments[0].name' but I have error that name is not defined. How to get this property?

`let experiments = [ {name: "C200929R01_SizeMarker", file: experiments[0].name + ".xrrx"} ];`

Comment: Set `experiments[n].file` *after* initializing `experiments` (with just the `name` property).

Answer (score 0):

Until that closing `]` experiments indeed won't be defined.

If your just trying to save typing the name in twice, you could retructure like ->

```js
const name = "C200929R01_SizeMarker";
let experiments = [ {name, file: name + ".xrrx"} ];

console.log(experiments);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
let experiments = [ {name: "C200929R01_SizeMarker", file: experiments[0].name + ".xrrx"} ];
```

When you are asigning file: experiments[0].name, experiments[0] is not defined yet, so you have different options:

```
let experiments = [{name: "C200929R01_SizeMarker"}];
experiments[0].file = experiments[0].name + ".xrrx";
```

Or using the option described in the previous answer